# Authorization check of travis webhook in nodejs

Tags: node.js, travis-ci

I've written the beginnings of a nodejs app to receive webhook notifications from travis-ci. What I'm stuck on is the inability to match my constructed sha2 hash of my combined `username/repostory` plus my Travis user token. The first piece comes along in the `Travis-Repo-Slug` header and the second piece is in my profile/info page at travis-ci.org. Here's what my code looks like:

```
var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(repoSlug + userToken).digest('hex');
```

The value of `hash` does not equal the value I find in the `Authorization` header as I would expect it to be:

```
if (hash == req.get('Authorization')) {
// authorized request
```

I've been following the documentation here http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/notifications/ but perhaps in staring at this all day I've missed something obvious. Does anyone have suggestions on what may be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out... I realized my travis access key wasn't the one currently configured in the github repo's webhook configuration. Travis uses this one as part of its hash when talking to my webhook. Hope someone finds this useful :)